# kendo text editor should not reset its formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-editor

I want to prevent [Kendo UI Editor](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/index) from resetting its formatting as the user types. Any hack or something will be helpful.

For example:

Type in some text in editor at the end (test) and change the formatting to heading. Press return or enter. It will change the formatting.[image: First Snapshot]
[image: Second Snapshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it... It was in their demo. I am closing the question. [Follow the link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor#defaulttools-array)

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<script>
var defaultTools = kendo.ui.Editor.defaultTools;

defaultTools["insertLineBreak"].options.shift = false;
defaultTools["insertParagraph"].options.shift = true;

$("#editor").kendoEditor();
</script>
```

Comment: I saw your post in the queue pre-edit. In future, you can flag the answer for mod attention, I only saw your comment because a community member drew my attention to it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes (edit happened)that was because someone told me from community, that i should avoid posting links to external website(for future, may be link does not exist). Can you guide me for how to flag the answer "In future, you can flag the answer for mod attention"

Comment: You can still see your own deleted post; on it is a 'flag' option, pick the 'in need of moderator attention' option and explain that you edited the answer and request that it is undeleted.